# How to get duration of Audio Stream and continue audio streaming from any point

Tags: android, audio-streaming, android-mediaplayer

**Description:**

I have following code for an Audio player. I can continue Audio playback from any duration by clicking on Progress Bar(between 0-to-mediaplayer.getDuration()). It is working perfectly for Audio playback.

**Problem in Audio Streaming:**

- When I stream an Audio file from an internet server (say s3-bucket)
  it starts streaming correctly.
- But mediaPlayer.getDuration() and mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()
  return wrong values. At the beginning of streaming
  mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() returns 5 hours.
- Due to this I am not able to continue Audio streaming from a
  specified duration of Stream (0-to-Stream Duration).

**Questions:**

1. How can I get the duration of an Audio stream
2. How can I continue Audio Streaming from a specified duration. For
   example for a file of 10-minute duration, I want to start streaming from 6th
   minute.

**Code:**

```
public class MyAudioPlayer extends Activity 
implements OnClickListener{


    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
    private boolean isPaused=false;
    private boolean isStop = true;

    String filePath = null;
    String productName = null;

    ImageButton btnPlay = null;
    ImageButton btnPause = null;
    ImageButton btnReset = null;
    ImageButton btnStop = null;

    AudioManager audioManager = null;
    SeekBar volControl = null;
    SeekBar progressControl = null;
    TextView progressText = null;
    long durationInMillis = -1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ltd_audio_player);

        volControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.player_volume);
        progressControl = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.player_seekbar);
        progressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player_progress_text);

        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_player_play); 

        btnPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_player_pause);  

        btnReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_player_reset); 

        btnStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ic_player_stop);   

        btnPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnPause.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnReset.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);

        filePath = getIntent().getExtras().getString("localPath");

        this.setPlayer();
        this.resetAndStartPlayer();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();   
        isPaused=false;
        progressText.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        isPaused=true;
    }
    private void setProgressControl() {
        int maxVolume = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        int curVolume = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

        progressControl.setMax(maxVolume);
        progressControl.setProgress(curVolume);
        progressControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekbar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });     
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.ic_player_play:
            if(isStop==true){
                try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }else{
                mediaPlayer.start();
                isStop = true;
            }
            break;
        case R.id.ic_player_pause:
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            break;
        case R.id.ic_player_reset:
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            break;
        case R.id.ic_player_stop:
            isStop = true;
            progressControl.setProgress(0);
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            break;
        }

    }
    private void resetAndStartPlayer(){
        try {
            if(filePath!=null){
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void setPlayer(){

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();    

        mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
                progressControl.setSecondaryProgress((progressControl.getMax()/100)*percent);

            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                isStop=false;
                durationInMillis = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                MyAudioPlayer.this.setProgressControl();
            }
        });
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mediaPlayer.release();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
    protected void setProgressText() {
        durationInMillis = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        int curVolume = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        long HOUR = 60*60*1000;
        if(progressText!=null){
            if(durationInMillis>HOUR){
                progressText.setText(String.format("%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS", new Date(curVolume))
                        +" / "+String.format("%1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS", new Date(durationInMillis)));
            }else{
                progressText.setText(String.format("%1$tM:%1$tS", new Date(curVolume))
                        +" / "+String.format("%1$tM:%1$tS", new Date(durationInMillis)));
            }
        }       
    }
    private Runnable onEverySecond=new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if (mediaPlayer!=null) {
                progressControl.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

                MyAudioPlayer.this.setProgressText();
            }

            if (!isPaused) {
                progressText.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 1000);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Time is displayed above the progress bar.

**Time: 'Current Duration'/'Total Duration'**

[image]

Comment: @Arif: i am working on creating a mediaplayer and if you solved the issue will you email me the code? abuhamzah09 at gmail dot com

Comment: what control is the `LTDAudioPlayer` ?

Comment: @AbuHamzah it was MyAudioPlayer instead of LTDAudioPlayer

Answer (score 13):

Hope that it might solve your problem.

**1) Duration and Progress of Audio Stream**

I have looked into your code, you have a major error in your code to calculate time. You create new Date(durationInMillis). Date adds your locallity i.e GMT+XX hours, that is why you are getting 5- hours in the beginnging of streaming. You should use following method to calculate currentProgress/duration.

```
protected void setProgressText() {

    final int HOUR = 60*60*1000;
    final int MINUTE = 60*1000;
    final int SECOND = 1000;

    int durationInMillis = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    int curVolume = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

    int durationHour = durationInMillis/HOUR;
    int durationMint = (durationInMillis%HOUR)/MINUTE;
    int durationSec = (durationInMillis%MINUTE)/SECOND;

    int currentHour = curVolume/HOUR;
    int currentMint = (curVolume%HOUR)/MINUTE;
    int currentSec = (curVolume%MINUTE)/SECOND;

    if(durationHour>0){
        System.out.println(" 1 = "+String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d/%02d:%02d:%02d", 
                currentHour,currentMint,currentSec, durationHour,durationMint,durationSec));            
    }else{
        System.out.println(" 1 = "+String.format("%02d:%02d/%02d:%02d", 
                currentMint,currentSec, durationMint,durationSec));
    }
}
```

**2) Scrubbing for Stream.**

MediaPlayer allows scrubbing of audio stream. I have implemented it in one of my projects, but it takes some time. It takes some time to resume audio streaming from another location.

Answer (score 3):

First big problem is your order of initialization:
you call getDuration before you actually call setDataSource in resetAndStartPlayer.
How is MediaPlayer supposed to know duration without data source?

Here's how to do that properly:

1. call MediaPlayer.setDataSource() in Activity.onCreate
2. execute AsyncTask, in its doInBackground call MediaPlayer.prepare(), this will take a while if it's streaming from http, but after it finishes, player should know lenght of media
3. in the AsyncTask.onPostExecute call MediaPlayer.getDuration(), which should succeed if stream was opened successfully; afterwards you may call MediaPlayer.start()

Important things:

- getDuration works after prepare was called
- prepare may take longer time, and should be called in other thread
- you may also use prepareAsync and avoid AsyncTask, then you'd use setOnPreparedListener callback to call getDuration

Comment: I appreciate your interest in solving the problem. I have modified the code to getDuration after mediaPlayer is prepared in mediaPlayer.onPrepared()...
As I mentioned that the problem was in audio streaming, it is still there. When I stream the audio even smaller one. GetDuration returns me 6-hours and something. But when I play audio from sdcard the same code returns correct duration.

Comment: Post example url of your remote stream.